# Is data warehouse monitoring same as database monitoring?

Tags: mysql, oracle, data-warehouse, monitoring

I have a requirement, where data warehouse population is to be monitored. I am in confusion, and needed a clear picture. Is data warehouse different than database?

eg. For monitoring database we would monitor its **availability, tablespace, cache, connections and other advanced metrics.**

On what parameters can we monitor data warehouse?

Comment: Which DBMS? You've tagged for both MySQL and Oracle which is a bit weird.

Comment: My company's server uses both MySQL and Oracle as database. I need to know if monitoring database is similar as monitoring data warehousing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "On what parameters can we monitor data warehouse?".

Exactly the same ones that you use for monitoring an OLTP database. You might want to pay more attention to things like slow query log (MySQL) for a DW, but that should be on the radar for an OLTP system also.

The common "gotchas" may change, but databases all sit on machines with disk, RAM, CPU and network connections. Bottlenecks can and do occur with any/all of these depending on your hardware (notably RAID - most database apps tend to be I/O bound), your application (and its configuration) and your network bandwidth.